# No Suitable Constructor Exists - Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, pass-by-reference, function-definition

I started a simple coding project for myself today and I cannot figure out this error or how to combat it. The error I am getting occurs during my `do` loop. More specifically, it occurs with each function call that passes `Nums` as a parameter. The error states `no suitable constructor exists to convert from to "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> [10]" to "std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>"`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

```
//This program checks to see if a multiplied vector value is odd or even
//CheckOddEven.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int setSize(int size, vector <int> Nums) //Sets vector size to user defined size
{
        //Prompt user to enter an integer to establish array size
        cout << "How many integers would you like to multiply?: ";

        //Store user input to size
        cin >> size;

        //Resize vector to user size
        Nums.resize(size);

        return size;
}

vector <int> setNum(int size, int x, vector <int> Nums) //Sets values in each index
{
        //Insertion loop to Nums vector
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                cout << "Enter integer #" << i + 1 << ": ";
                cin >> x;
                Nums.push_back(x); //Assigns value into vector
        }

        return Nums;
}

int doMath(vector <int> Nums, int result)
{
        //Loop through Nums vector and multiply all values
        accumulate(Nums.begin(), Nums.end(), result, multiplies<int>());

        return result;
}

string oddEven(int result, string msg) //Check if int is even by seeing if there is a remainder
{
        //If no remainder exists then positive
        if (result % 2 == 0)
                {
                        msg += "positive.";
                }
                
        //If remainder exists then negative
        else
        {
                msg += "negative.";
        }

        return msg;
}

void Display(int result, string msg)
{
        cout << "The product of your integers is " << result << endl;
        cout << msg;
}

char checkCont(char cont)
{
        //Asks user if they want to check another integer
        cout << "Would you like to check another? (y/n)" << endl;

        //Assigns input as char into cont
        cin >> cont;

        //Displays exit message and ends do-while
        if (cont == 'n' || cont == 'N')
        {
                cout << "Thank you for using the Odd-Even Checker!" << endl;
                cout << "Have a great day!" << endl;
        }

        return 'z';
}

int main()
{
        int size; //User defined vector size
        string msg = "The number you calculated is ";
        char cont = ' '; //Char value for checking another vector
        vector <int> Nums[10]; //Create int vector with predetermined size..can be changed with resize
        int x; //User numbers
        int result;

        cout << "Welcome to the Odd-Even Checker!" << endl;
        cout << "This program multiplies a given amount of numbers, then checks to see if the answer is even or odd." << endl;

        do //Requires to run at least once
        {
                setSize(size, Nums);
                setNum(size, x, Nums);
                doMath(Nums, result);
                oddEven(result, msg);
                Display(result, msg);
                checkCont(cont);
        } while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y'); //end do-while

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C. Don't misuse tags.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array of vectors

```
vector <int> Nums[10];
```

but passing this array to functions that expects a scalar object of the vector type

```
int setSize(int size, vector <int> Nums);

//...

setSize(size, Nums);
```

Maybe instead of the array you mean a vector with 10 elements like

```
vector <int> Nums(10);
```

or just an empty vector

```
vector <int> Nums;
```

It seems there exists one more problem that you are not passing the vector by reference. So for example the function `setSize` deals with a copy of the passed vector.

As a result this statement within the function

```
Nums.resize(size);
```

does not make a sense.

Change the type of the vector function parameter in functions where it is required to a referenced type like

```
int setSize(int size, vector <int> &Nums);
                                  ^^^^^^
```

Pay attention that the value of the parameter size is not used within the function, So the parameter `size` does not make a sense.

Also this function does not make a sense

```
int doMath(vector <int> Nums, int result)
{
        //Loop through Nums vector and multiply all values
        accumulate(Nums.begin(), Nums.end(), result, multiplies<int>());

        return result;
}
```

the variable results is not being changed after calling the algorithm `std::accumulate`.

Also you are passing an uninitialized variable result

```
int result;
```

You should at least write

```
long long int doMath( const std::vector<int> &Nums )
{
        //Loop through Nums vector and multiply all values
    long long result = std::accumulate(Nums.cbegin(), Nums.cend(), 1ll, std::multiplies<long long>());

    return result;
}
```

You should split your program into small sub-programs and test each used function separately because it seems you do not understand what you are doing. After that you can combain all sub-programs in one program.

For example to test the function `setSize` you could write a simple program like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>::size_type setSize( std::vector<int> &Nums )
{
    //Prompt user to enter an integer to establish array size
    std::cout << "How many integers would you like to multiply?: ";

    //Store user input to size
    std::vector<int>::size_type size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;

    //Resize vector to user size
    Nums.resize( size );

    return size;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> Nums;
    
    auto size = setSize( Nums );
    
    if ( size == Nums.size() )
    {
        std::cout << "The function works correctly.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Something is wrong with the function!\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

After you will be sure that the function works as expected you can add it to the main program.